Trying to understand spectral geometry
Currently I'm studying Riemannian Geometry, in particular I started to learn something about spectral geometry like the famous results of Lichnerowicz and Obata about the first eigenvalues of a closed Riemannian manifold. I read that some geometric aspects can be studied by searching the solutions of the eigenvalue equation: $\Delta u=-\lambda u$. The results to which I am referring are the following:
Lichnerowicz theorem: if $Ric \geq (n-1)g$ then the first eigenvalue is $\geq n$
Obata theorem: in the same hypothesis, the first eigenvalue is equal to $n$ if and only if the manifold is isometric to a sphere.
My questions are: I don't really understand the equation, are we searching all the eigenvalues with respect to all the sufficient regular functions on the manifold ("sufficient" means that the laplacian makes sense)?   what does the first eigenvalue means (maybe the lowest)? How can the eigenvalues can give information about the metric $g$ (is because the definition of Laplace-Beltrami operator depends on the metric)?
I'm trying to have a better intuition about this perspective of Riemannian Geometry.
Thank you all

Related: wiki page: can you hear the shape of a drum
